# Running two instances of VisualSVN Server on one machine?

Tags: visualsvn-server

Is it possible to run more than one instance of VisualSVN Server on a single machine? I would like to have one instance accessible only from the local network (blocked on firewall) and the other one accessible from the Internet. I attempted to run the installer again but it refers to the already installed instance.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. You can run two VisualSVN Server instances running on different servers and store Subversion repositories on network share if you need.